# The simplest way to get to and from Wagah border ceremony

Tags: india, transportation, events, wagah

I will be staying in Amritsar for a few days but will be on a tight schedule.

Since I want to see the [Wagah border ceremony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagah_border_ceremony), what do you think would be the best way to get from Amritsar to Wagah, see the ceremony and come back to Amritsar immediately after the closing ends?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

three Indian ways to get there.

1. Shared Autos.
2. Buses
3. Private Cabs.

Shared autos will take somewhat around 1 hour to reach there and they will not start until it is full.

Buses you can catch from Amritsar Bus stand and there you must reach a bit early - 45 min drive + 30 min wait in bus.

Private cabs are costlier, on which I traveled took 10 INR/km and it was around 40 km.

The ceremony starts about 5:15PM and you have to be there 15 min early to get a seat and at least an hour early to get front rows. 
You have to add 10 min of walk from parking to ceremony place, so plan accordingly.