# What do I need to do to see the Wagha/Wagah border ceremony from the Pakistani side?

Tags: borders, pakistan, events, lahore, wagah

The [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wagah) article on the Wagah/Wagha "Beating Retreat" ceremony mentions that I can take Minibus No. 4 from Lahore to the Pakistani side of the border, but the section on how to get seated for the actual event only seems to cover what to do on the Indian side. It does mention that the Pakistani side draws a smaller crowd.

An existing [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4837/47855) on this site covers the *Indian* side.

If I want to see the border ceremony from the *Pakistani* side as a foreigner, is it acceptable to simply show up before the ceremony, or do I need to do anything, such as buy a ticket or obtain travel clearance?

To be clear, my nationality does require a visa to enter Pakistan, but that is not part of the question. Assuming that I have (or can obtain) the proper visa, can I simply travel from Lahore straight to the border and expect to be seated as a spectator?

I'm not asking about how to *cross* the border there, only view the border ceremony.

Comment: How did it go for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can answer that question from personal experience, I have been to that ceremony several times.

- There are no tickets or registration, It's free. (May have to pay a nominal car parking fee)
- There is no NOC to obtain, however it is a sensitive area and for foreigners it will be really advisable to carry evidence of the legality of their stay at that time.
- You can take any form of transport to the venue, that area is well connected with the rest of Lahore via the ring road and an Uber/Careem will be your best bets. If you do this, I would advise discussing and arranging the return trip with the same driver.

**However**, Long gone are the days where you could just show up at the venue sometime before the ceremony and expect to be seated. Now you have to arrive well in advance, not because of any formalities but because of the sheer number of people expecting to be seated on any given day.

Try to reach at max 2 PM in Winters, 3 PM in Summers. Expect multiple security checks.

Last but not least, The car park for that venue is quite far away. It is easily 1KM+. There is absolutely no way that you will be allowed to take your car, or any public transport to go farther than that. So it is a long walk. Be prepared for that.

**Bonus Tip:** If you have any friends in Pakistan that have family or friends in the security forces, they might be able to arrange premium seats for you if the coordination takes place in time, and not on the last minute. This is free as well.

And by the way, that ceremony is Awesome!

> What do I need to do to see the Wagha/Wagah border ceremony from the Pakistani side?

Just show up well in time.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! A 1km walk is no problem at all.